# Concatenate values of two arrays

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Let's assume I have an two arrays and I want to merge every value with the other value of the array.

**Array 1**

> ```
> array (size=2)
>   0 => 1
>   1 => 2
> ```

**Array 2**

> ```
> array (size=2)
>   0 => 3
>   1 => 4
> ```

**Wanted result array / string:**

> ```
> array (size=4)
>   0 => '1,3'
>   1 => '1,4'
>   2 => '2,3'
>   3 => '2,4'
> ```

I can't get my head around it. Obviously I would need to merge every one array key/value with the other ones. Is there a more elegant way then doing this in a while/foreach loop?

Comment: so what you have tried?

Comment: I thnk the title concantenate values of two arrays. Would be more suitable.

Comment: Concatenate*, apologies. @s1x

Comment: Thanks. It's sometimes really difficult to describe your problem in words, especially if you're not sure what your problem is :-).

Comment: No problem at all. When you mention `merging` people usually assume `array_merge()` which is basicly extending one array with the other. Concatenate is basicly pasting pieces of data together. Which is what you wanted. Trying to properly formulate what you tried and what you want helps people help you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `foreach` loop inside a `foreach` loop. (Actualy, you will have to loop through both arrays to get a concatenated product of both arrays, you don't actually need two `foreach` loops). You could mix: `whiles`, `foreach`, `for`, or php filter/intersect array functions

## Example

```
$array1 = array(1,2);
$array2 = array(3,4);
$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $item1){
   foreach($array2 as $item2){
      $result[] = $item1.','.$item2;
   }
}
```

https://eval.in/215001

your result array Length will be `array1.Length * array2.Length`

## 2d arrays

You could also put an array inside an array like this:

```
$array1 = array(1,2);
$array2 = array(3,4);
$result = array();

foreach ($array1 as $item1){
   foreach($array2 as $item2){
      $result[] = array($item1, $item2);
   }
}
//$result[0][0] = 1 -- $result[0][1] = 3
//$result[1][0] = 1 -- $result[1][1] = 4
//$result[2][0] = 2 -- $result[2][1] = 3
//$result[3][0] = 2 -- $result[3][1] = 4
```

We call this a 2d (2 dimensional) array, because you could grapicly display this as a grid, like displayed here above. If you would put an Array, inside an Array inside an Array, you would call this a 3 dimensional array, etc.

print_r($result); in php:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 4
        )

)
```

Comment: checked your output? syntax error $item1.','$item2;

Comment: Fixed it, no i didnt, i wrote just plain text.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$a= array ('0' => 1,'1' => 2);
$b= array ('0' => 3,'1' => 4);
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++) {
  for($j=0; $j<count($b); $j++) {
    $newarr[]= $a[$i].','.$b[$j];
  }
}
print_r($newarr);//Array ( [0] => 1,3 [1] => 1,4 [2] => 2,3 [3] => 2,4 )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$a=array('1','2');
$b=array('3','4');
$res=array();
for($i=0;$i<count($a);$i++)
{
    foreach($b as $bb)
    {
        $res[]=strval($a[$i].','.$bb);
    }


}
print_r($res);//output=Array ( [0] => 1,3 [1] => 1,4 [2] => 2,3 [3] => 2,4 )
```

Comment: @Rakesh Sharma $bb is variable that hold the value of $b check this http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php